# google chrome tray icon broken in gnome 3.6

Tags: gnome3, chrome, icons, tray

[image]
Google Chrome starts up with the correct tray icon but when restarted it has the broken tray icon. Has anyone filed a bug report about this? And is there any workaround at present?

Comment: I had this problem as well, all I had to do was reset. Alt+F2 then r then enter.